# Display y axis from 0 to 100 in Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to display my data and wanted to set the y axis to show always from 0 to 100 or from 10 to 60.

I used "set_ylim()" and it worked with a small list but then I tried to put my data in that had datetime as x and a int as y and this didn't worked or the list is too long.

the data list looks like this: [ [ ] , [ ] , [ ] ]
and the first list has datetime.datetime()
the second is an int that mostly has 20,22 and 21 repeating and the third looks similiar to the second.

using the small list with set_ylim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7MYL.png

with my data and set_ylim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dGcL.png

with my data working without set_ylim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRD7F.png

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy
import time
import datetime

#####read data####
data = ([datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 35), 
        datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 37), 
        datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 39), 
        datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 41), 
        datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 43), 
        datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 7, 33, 45)], 

        ['20', '20', '22', '20', '20', '22'], 

        ['30', '32', '31', '30', '32', '31'])
##################

#####plot data#####
fig = plt.figure()
#axis1#
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)

#axis2#
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)


def update(i):

    #readData(data)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()

    ax1.set_ylim((10,60))
    ax2.set_ylim((0,100))

    #ax1.plot([1,2], [20,30])
    #ax2.plot([2,3],[2,3])
    ax1.plot(data[0],data[1],color="red")
    ax2.plot(data[0],data[2],color="blue")

    #tweak style#
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

###################

a = anim.FuncAnimation(fig,update,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question - just enough to reproduce the problem.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Comment: If `n = 10000; b = [20,22, 21]*n; c = [30,32,31]*n; data =[range(3*n),b,c]` is a fair representation of your data then your example code produces a graph that looks reasonable.

Comment: Using datetimes also don't affect the graph produced - `start = datetime.datetime(2020,5,15); dt = datetime.timedelta(minutes=3); x = [start+(dt*t) for t in range(n*3)]; data[0] = x`.

Comment: I just edited my code and you can just copy , paste it in a file and run it with Python3 with matplot installed. My problem still occurs with a very small amount of data (6 readings) unrealistic but to test. Thanks for even trying to help.

edit: note if you want to use normal int as x then you need to remove the date formatter under #tweak style#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plotting strings - change them to ints

```
ax1.plot(data[0],[int(thing) for thing in data[1]],color="red")
ax2.plot(data[0],[int(thing) for thing in data[2]],color="blue")
```

Comment: I looked at "You are plotting strings" checked if datetime was a string but after looking at your code I realised that not the x axis is the fault. And I really don't know how I oversaw this that I didn't used numbers but strings. I really Thank you very much. So I tought that these were integers but they weren't.